# Another Journey to the Land of Puzz

Tags: word, rhyme, wordplay

The Wonderful Wanderful land of Puzz
Is where you and I now are;
Where magazines eat wheeled things,
And the whole world is bizarre.

To prove my point, I found a joint
Where brochures came to cope.
"I can't `_ _ _ _ _ (_)` this `(_) _ _ _ _`,"
A weeping `_ _ _ _ _ _` `_ _ (_) _ _`.

"Don't `_ _ (_) _ _` away here," I declared.
"We'll fix this with a plan.
Have you tried `_ _ _ _ _`? If you're from Puzz,
you `_ _ _` buy it like bread -- in `(_) _ _`s!"

"I cannot use my funds," he said,
"As my `(_) _ _ _` will not `_ _ _ (_) _ _`.
I have a rifle `_ _ _ _ _ (_)`, though,
And the river `_ _ _ _`'s where they sit!"

He snagged a rifle full of `_ _ _ _`
and said, "`_ _ (_) _` me to the `(_) _ _ _`!"
When we arrived, we found a tree
and `_ (_) _ _`ed there until dark.

At the `_ _ _ (_)` of a hill, we stood quite still
His gun `_ _ _ _`ed to his eye
When a `_ _ _ _` away, around midday,
A `_ _ (_) _` came wandering by.

Aiming at the poor thing's `(_) _ _ _`,
He shot it `_ _ _ _`. 'Twas dead!
`_ _ _ _` at his home, he stripped its coat,
Ate just its `_ (_) _ _`, then fled...

I wandered to a nearby `_ _ _`
Which `_ (_) _ _ _`! Or, so I'm told.
Though my poor teeth can't gnaw their slaw
of `_ _ (_) _ _` and `_ (_) _`s of gold.

How odd, the `(_) _ _ _ _ _ _` of this `_ _ _ _ _ _ _`.
I'm struck without comment.
Yet after `_ _ _ _ _ _ _` my tab,
I felt oddly `_ _ _ _ _ _ (_)`!

---

A funny, winged fellow
Does his makeup in a field.
If you can, **name this non-man

and the small objects he wields.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't see any unifying underlying pattern like in the previous puzzle like this, but a lot of the gaps are quite easy to fill in. EDIT: actually, after trying it in practice, I've found a pattern:

> In each verse, two of the missing words are actually the same word, with different meanings. In fact, it's *possible* (though I'm not sure) that the same can be said of the other two!

Also, the second and fourth lines of each verse rhyme.

> The Wonderful Wanderful land of Puzz
>   Is where you and I now are;
>   Where magazines eat wheeled things,
>   And the whole world is bizarre.
>
> To prove my point, I found a joint
>   Where brochures came to cope.
>   "I can't `DIGES(T)` this `(M)OPED`,"
>   A weeping `DIGEST` `MO(P)ED`.
>
> "Don't `QU(A)IL` away here," I declared.
>   "We'll fix this with a plan.
>   Have you tried `QUAIL`? If you're from Puzz,
>   you `CAN` buy it like bread -- in `(C)AN`s!"
>
> "I cannot use my funds," he said,
>   "As my `(B)ANK` will not `PER(M)IT`.
>   I have a rifle `PERMI(T)`, though,
>   And the river `BANK`'s where they sit!"
>
> He snagged a rifle full of `LEAD`
>   and said, "`LE(A)D` me to the `(P)ARK`!"
>   When we arrived, we found a tree
>   and `P(A)RK`ed there until dark.
>
> At the `FOO(T)` of a hill, we stood quite still
>   His gun `COCK`ed to his eye
>   When a `FOOT` away, around midday,
>   A `CO(C)K` came wandering by.
>
> Aiming at the poor thing's `(B)ACK`,
>   He shot it `DOWN`. 'Twas dead!
>   `BACK` at his home, he stripped its coat,
>   Ate just its `D(O)WN`, then fled...
>
> I wandered to a nearby `BAR`
>   Which `R(O)CKS`! Or, so I'm told.
>   Though my poor teeth can't gnaw their slaw
>   of `RO(C)KS` and `B(A)R`s of gold.
>
> How odd, the `(C)ONTENT` of this `CLOSING`.
>   I'm struck without comment.
>   Yet after `CLOSING` my tab,
>   I felt oddly `CONTEN(T)`!

Letters circled:

> TMPACBMTAPATCBOOCACT

which rearrange to

> BAT COMPACT BAT COMPACT,

in which the repetition fits with the overall theme of the puzzle.

So the answer to

> A funny, winged fellow
>   Does his makeup in a field.
>   If you can, name this non-man
>   and the small objects he wields.

is

> he's a BAT wielding a makeup COMPACT.

Thanks to @COTO and @CodeNewbie and @alexmc for finding some of the words!

Comment: May as well plug in any clues I get into your solution. ;)

Comment: @COTO I thought "closing" too, but can't make sense of "content of this closing". Doesn't matter anyway; no special letters to be found there!

Comment: At the FOOT of a hill... His gun COCKed to his eye... when a FOOT away, a COCK came wandering by

Comment: "Closing" as in "the closing of the poem", I think.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Yep, I just came up with FOOT simultaneously! Thanks for COCK - I'll add it.

Comment: I think it's "wandered to a nearby BAR" and "BARs of gold".

Comment: I'm guessing the last clue is "Which ROCKS!" and "of ROCKS and BARs of gold".

Comment: *lol* @ "BAT COMBS PACT TACT COMP". Methinks we got something wrong somewhere. :D

Comment: @COTO Yeah, but BAT COMBS could still be right! Hopefully the OP will give us a nudge in the right direction...

Comment: The "makeup in a field" comment makes me think that "COMPACT", as in a make-up compact, is one of the words in the anagram. The "small object" also implies "COMPACT". So the phrase is going to be something like "X X COMPACT COMPACT", with X repeated.

Comment: I'm guessing BAT BAT COMPACT COMPACT, but that would mean that an 'S' somewhere is supposed to be an 'A'.

Comment: This looks really good! You have two words which were not what I had intended. I'll give you a bit to try to puzzle them out before I tell you which ones! :)

Comment: Maybe "Aiming at the poor thing's HEAD / He shot it ONCE. 'Twas dead! / ONCE at his home, he stripped its coat / Ate just its HEAD, and fled."?

Comment: Except the sense of HEAD would be the same in both places, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: Since this is still sitting here and I'd like to check you off, the two incorrect words are 'WASTE' and 'CLOSING' - the context is meant to hint that the first is some sort of game bird, while the second is simply a different word indicating the end of something more specific.

Comment: I think the 'WASTE' one is meant to be 'QUAIL'.

Comment: @BaileyM Who cares about CLOSING - it doesn't have any circled letters :-P If alexmc is right, then the circled letters form an anagram of BAT COMPACT BAT COMPACT, which I suppose would fit the repeating-words theme!

Comment: ...ah, yes, you're right about that. :P The word I was looking for there was EVENING, just for completeness's sake. Your little furry friend in a (baseball) field is indeed a BAT with a COMPACT and a COMPACT BAT! Update the answer to QUAIL and I'll mark this correct.